# Usage of "attach" for human

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

I know this term is used for [tags, labels, emotional connections, etc.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/attach), but I am not sure I can use it for a sarcastic purpose to express my negative idea about a person who follows me everywhere and imposes his/her ideas about me to me against my will like this:

> S/he attaches her/himself to me everywhere I am!

If not so what the other phrases or terms do you suggest me for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using *attach* does sound a bit formal for describing someone who follows you around (I am not sure what you mean by "imposes his/her ideas about me to me") in an insecure and unwelcome manner. But *attach* could be used for this meaning, as could the adjective *overly-attached.*  Other more casual expressions are:

- She clings to me
- She latches onto me
- He follows me around like a
  puppy dog
- He is clingy
- She doesn't give me any space

Comment: +1, how about "sticky"-i.e., "he is sticky"? My Italian-English dictionary reads this word together "clingy".

Comment: _Sticky_ doesn't sound right to my Canadian ears for the figurative meaning, only the literal.

Comment: @ShawnMooney +1 At first thanks for your answer and at second: Imposes means forcing hie/her ideas to me but I do not know if this verb is not used for this meaning in  general.

Comment: Use could use the phrase "human leach" though it would be considered negative if not rude. Usage should be only if you do not intend to have further communications with the person.

Comment: It is not "human leach" but "butt-leach" or "ass-leach":http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ass-leach. Surely it is highly offensive to use but I am sure even if I tell him/her in a face to face situation s/he will continue to his/her "moral job". No scape of my lovers! :"))((

Answer (score 1):

"Attach" is absolutely fine in the situation you describe.