# What are the differences between "imposing an idea" and "forcing an idea" on others?

Tags: difference, word-choice

I used it in my previous question [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/usage-of-attach-for-human) which seems according to the answer and the comment which I received by Shawn Mooney, ***Imposing an idea on others*** is different to ***forcing an idea on others*** and cannot be replaced with it. I want to know the differences between these two.

Comment: user3, the best I can think of is that "forcing an idea" could be the result of a strategic persuasion technique, whereas "imposing an idea" implies a violent, also moral (and not only physical), act on other people.

Comment: So I choose imposing! Now it is the time to find a solution for it like "shut up"! :))

Comment: @user37324: I edited to remove your distracting but irrelevant use of the wrong preposition (you *impose something **on** someone*, not ***to** them*). And since we have no context to define *which* others, it seems more natural here to simply refer to *others*, rather than ***the** others*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two expressions are fairly close in meaning and can be used interchangeably with the following nuances:

***"force an idea on the others"*** implies that the idea was opposed by the others but through some sort of aggression (verbal or otherwise), the others had to accept the idea.

***"impose an idea on the others"*** gives more of an impression that the others didn't want to go along with idea for whatever reason but acquiesced though they might feel there was either some coersion or at the least, an obligation to accept the idea.

Comment: +1 Thanks. So was it a correct usage of "imposing an idea" in the link provided in the context?

Comment: You did use the correct expression because the "hanger-on" gave unsolicited opinions to you, about you.  (The nerve!) :-)

Comment: :)) Thanks! one more vote for the comment! Is it hanger-on or hanger one?!

Comment: Thanks for vote! It's "hanger-on", a title for someone who attaches one's self to another person or group.

Comment: Again another vote! I learned a lot. In Persian we say it hanger one.

Comment: I think this is a spurious distinction. If there's any difference at all (and I'm far from convinced there is anyway), it's probably that *imposing* tends to be used more in contexts where the *imposed **idea*** does actually lead to *imposed **action***. If an "idea" is "forced" on you, that might just mean you were obliged to consciously reflect on something you didn't want to think about at all, whereas if it's "imposed" on you, there's more the implication that you were obliged to ***agree** with it, and act accordingly*.

Comment: Aha! It made it more clear.

Comment: "Spurious" is a bit strong, @FumbleFingers, since I opened my answer with the acknowledgement that the two expressions are very close in meaning.  For the new speakers, synonyms of "spurious" include: false - sham - counterfeit - bogus - mock - phony.  All a bit strong for a slight difference of opinion. :-)

Comment: @Kristina: Sorry if you think the word "spurious" sounds excessively condemnatory. I don't really think there's *any* difference in meaning as such, so I disagree with the idea that either word actual carries a "nuance" in itself. I think there *is* a slight tendency to use "impose" in contexts where the *behaviour* of others is altered by whatever is imposed, but I don't see that justifies implying to learners that they should learn/understand/remember the incredibly subtle distinction you make here (which I don't even think is a *tendency*, to be honest).

Answer (score 1):

To my British ears "impose" is more appropriate for an idea, unless you couple it with some metaphor that implies the use of (physical) force:

"In that school they forced out-dated dogma down our throats"

You can't physically force an idea into someone's head.

Comment: +1 Thanks! I don't want to use it as a physical statement.